Converting a number to a varchar, doing an operation, converting it back to a number in MySQL
I am trying to solve The Blunder challenge under MySQL database and I am running into an error in what I thought to be a correct answer:
SELECT CEIL(AVG(Salary) - AVG(CAST(REPLACE(CAST(Salary AS VARCHAR(255)), '0', '') AS DECIMAL(14,2)))) AS avg_error FROM Employees;
In plain words, I tried converting the Salary (which is originally of a number type) into a varchar, remove any 0s appearing in it, convert it back to a number. I then calculated the average of the error and took a ceiling of it.
However, when I run the code, I get the following error message:
`Compiler Message
Runtime Error
Error (stderr)
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(255)), '0', '') AS DECIMAL(14,2)))) AS avg_error
FROM Employees' at line 1
Your Output (stdout)
~ no response on stdout ~`
I don't know where I made a mistake. Could you tell me how I can fix this, and if there is another way of a solution?

You basically don't need to CAST the Value to `char, MySQL will do it for you
CREATE tABLE employee( ID int, name varchar(10), Salary int)

INSERT INTO employee VALUES (1,"test1", 1420)
  ,(2,"test2",2006)
  ,(3,'tEST3',2210)
  ,(4,"Name4", 3000)


Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0


SELECT AVG(SALARY) - AVG( REGEXP_REPLACE(Salary,'0','')) FROM employee




AVG(SALARY) - AVG( REGEXP_REPLACE(Salary,'0',''))




2061



SELECT CAST(AVG(SALARY) - AVG( REGEXP_REPLACE(Salary,'0','')) AS DECIMAL(10,2))  FROM employee




CAST(AVG(SALARY) - AVG( REGEXP_REPLACE(Salary,'0','')) AS DECIMAL(10,2))




2061.00



fiddle

Thank you. so I figured out that I had some problem with dangling parenthesis (not being closed out). The following gave me the correct result:
SELECT
CEIL(
AVG(Salary) -
AVG(
CAST(
REPLACE(Salary, '0', '') as decimal(14,2)
)
)
) AS avg_error
FROM Employees;
I am not sure what @RickJames had in mind about not using REPLACE. Do you see a way out?

this is the easiest way that i know of, so tryit

CAST(...) limits what you can give for a type. Check the documentation; you probably want CHAR instead of VARCHAR(255).
Do you really want to use REPLACE to change "306" into "36"?

Thank you, do you know a way to change 306 into 36 without using REPLACE?

REPLACE is the way to do it.  But it seems like a strange thing to be doing.
